# How to launch Google Map's Intent API from my ionic app via Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, android-intent, ionic-framework

I have seen a couple of post saying to launch a Google Maps Intent API to launch the turn by turn navigation. As some of the post suggest it's not possible to have the turn by turn navigation in your app using the JavaScript API(Correct me if I am wrong.) I'll have one option that is to use the intents in Google Maps API. Many of the answers give this code.

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=Taronga+Zoo,+Sydney+Australia");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

But I cannot put this code inside my JavaScript application as it is not JavaScript. how do I achieve this for my ionic app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using cordova - ionic, why don't you try [this plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/phonegap-launch-navigator). You can set the source and destination as shown in the plugin and also mention the `navigationMode: "turn-by-turn"` in the options.